# Pandas boxplot side by side for different DataFrame

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, overlap

Even though there are nice examples online about plotting side by side boxplots. With the way my data is set in two different pandas DataFrames and allready having sum subplots I have not been able to manage getting my boxplots next to each other in stead of overlapping.

my code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mpl.use('agg')

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(9,6))
month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
percentiles = [90,95,98]
nr = 0
for p in percentiles:  
    future_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(30,12)),columns = month)
    present_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(30,12)),columns = month)

    Future = future_data.as_matrix()
    Present = present_data.as_matrix()      

    pp = axarr[nr].boxplot(Present,patch_artist=True, showfliers=False)   
    fp = axarr[nr].boxplot(Future, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False)

    nr += 1
```

The results looks as follows:
[Overlapping Boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNb4e.jpg)

Could you help me out in how to makes sure the boxes are next to each other so I can compare them without being bothered by the overlap?

Thank you!

EDIT: I have reduced the code somewhat so it can run like this.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal runnable example? It seems more than half of the code is not relevant for the problem you want to ask about here.

Comment: Hi, I am not exactly sure what you mean. To get the plot I want I need this full code. I have taken out details that are not necessary. If I take out the patch_artist stuff, then someone might come up with an solution that doesn't support patch_artist. Last time I took out details someone told me the code was not complete so thus here a complete code. I am not trying to be lazy here, I just really need some assistance with this specific issue.

Comment: I cannot copy the code and run it, can I? So you need to come up with some code that allows people to help you that is similar enough to your real code, such that any given solution would apply. In this case, create some data to use within the code instead of loading files. And get rid of any styling that is not necessary (noone cares about the color of those elements).

Comment: ah, I understand. Thank you, I have added my code. Now it runs at once. Hope you can help :)

Comment: You are overlapping when you plot the graph for both the daraframe on the same axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to position your bars manually, i.e. providing the positions as array to the `position` argument of boxplot. Here it makes sense to shift one by -0.2 and the other by +0.2 to their integer position. You can then adjust the width of them to sum up to something smaller than the difference in positions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(9,6))
month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
percentiles = [90,95,98]
nr = 0
for p in percentiles:  
    future_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(30,12)),columns = month)
    present_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(30,12)),columns = month)

    Future = future_data.as_matrix()
    Present = present_data.as_matrix()      

    pp = axarr[nr].boxplot(Present,patch_artist=True, showfliers=False, 
                           positions=np.arange(Present.shape[1])-.2, widths=0.4)   
    fp = axarr[nr].boxplot(Future, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False,
                           positions=np.arange(Present.shape[1])+.2, widths=0.4)

    nr += 1  

axarr[-1].set_xticks(np.arange(len(month)))
axarr[-1].set_xticklabels(month)
axarr[-1].set_xlim(-0.5,len(month)-.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.