# geom_text not matching group aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, boxplot, predict

I'm pretty sure this is a silly question, but I've been stuck with it for a while now. I want to match the `geom_text()` to my means from `stat_summary` according to `My_group`

- the plot:

[image: my plot]

- my code:

```
### getting model's predictions:

mod1 <- lmer(MY_CONT ~  YEAR * GROUP_2 + (1|ID), data = data, REML = FALSE)

###

data$predictions <- predict(mod1)

### put model's predictions in a sep df:
dfPred <- data %>% group_by(YEAR, MY_GROUP) %>% rstatix::get_summary_stats(predictions)

### check it:

dfPred %>% select(YEAR, MY_GROUP, variable, n, mean)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  YEAR  MY_GROUP variable        n  mean
  <fct> <fct>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     G1       predictions    21  17.6
2 A     G2       predictions    21  18.5
3 B     G1       predictions    21  18.8
4 B     G2       predictions    21  19.1

### the model:

data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = YEAR, y = predictions)) +
  stat_boxplot(aes(x = YEAR, fill = MY_GROUP), geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.15, position = position_dodge(.75)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = MY_GROUP), 
               outlier.colour = "lightgrey", 
               outlier.shape = 19,
               outlier.size= 2, notch = T) +
  geom_text(data = dfPred, 
            aes(label = round(mean, 2),
                y = round(mean, 2) + 0.8)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP),
               fun = mean, geom = "point", 
               shape = 20, size= 3, color= "black",
               position = position_dodge(.75)) 

Warning message:
In stat_boxplot(aes(x = YEAR, fill = MY_GROUP), geom = "errorbar",  :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

**My Question:**

- **How can I put the means' labels according to their group** ? (MY_GROUP) ?
- *side question 1* : I get the fill warning, but it doesn't work without `fill`
- *side question 2* : The bars are showing the standard error aroung the means, right? not the 95%

- data (and more details on the model and on how I obtained the above effects [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603792/whats-the-appropriate-effect-size-estimate-and-power-analysis-for-post-hoc-re?noredirect=1#comment1121366_603792)):

```
data <- structure(list(PARTICIPANTS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                        10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                        14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
                                        17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
                                        20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), CONT_Y = c(19.44, 20.07, 19.21, 
                                                                                  16.35, 11.37, 12.82, 19.42, 18.94, 19.59, 20.01, 19.7, 17.92, 
                                                                                  18.78, 19.21, 19.27, 18.46, 19.52, 20.02, 16.19, 19.97, 13.83, 
                                                                                  15.93, 14.79, 21.55, 18.8, 19.42, 19.27, 19.37, 17.14, 14.45, 
                                                                                  17.63, 20.01, 20.28, 17.93, 19.36, 20.15, 16.06, 17.04, 19.16, 
                                                                                  20.1, 16.44, 18.39, 18.01, 19.05, 18.04, 19.69, 19.61, 16.88, 
                                                                                  19.02, 20.42, 18.27, 18.43, 18.08, 17.1, 19.98, 19.43, 19.71, 
                                                                                  19.93, 20.11, 18.41, 20.31, 20.1, 20.38, 20.29, 13.6, 18.92, 
                                                                                  19.05, 19.13, 17.75, 19.15, 20.19, 18.3, 19.43, 19.8, 19.83, 
                                                                                  19.53, 16.14, 21.14, 17.37, 18.73, 16.51, 17.51, 17.06, 19.42
                                        ), CATEGORIES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
                                                                                                                            "B"), class = "factor"), MY_GROUP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
                                                                                                                            ), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -84L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
 


### rename column:

data <- data %>%  rename(., YEAR = CATEGORIES)
```

Comment: ```stat_summary``` was also not matching the groups, but then I saw a post here recommending ```position_dodge(.75)``` and it worked, but it didn't work for ```geom_text()``` as well

Comment: Hi Larissa. Your example isn't fully reproducible, since we don't have `mod1` or `dfmodels`, but if you want to make the `geom_text` dodge, you could add `group = MY_GROUP` within the `aes` of `geom_text` (as well as the `position = position_dodge(0.75)` in `geom_text` _outside_ of the `aes` ). Also, you don't need stat_boxplot if you are using `geom_boxplot` to draw your boxes.

Comment: hi, @AllanCameron, oh, I thought it was! Now you should be able to reproduce it :) (my bad, I've been discussing the model a lot on CV, so I thought I've written it down)

Comment: yey! Now I got them aligned! thank you!! would you mind looking at the aside questions as well?  Concerning ```stat_boxplot```, if I comment that line, then my error bars are only a line (without --- on top and bottom lines) @AllanCameron